# how to detect any Link in HTMLString in webView? (Iphone)

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, hyperlink

if i want that i can detect the link appeared in my HTMLstring in webView...how can I do it?

I know in IB As we checkmark the box of auto detectable link... but I want to know programatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check the `dataDetectorTypes` property?

For example use this:

```
[[self content] setDataDetectorTypes: UIDataDetectorTypeAll];
```

You could use:

```
UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber
UIDataDetectorTypeLink
UIDataDetectorTypeAddress
UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent
UIDataDetectorTypeNone
UIDataDetectorTypeAll
```

[Reference-Link UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)